# Matrix Table independent Columns

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services

Right now I have a matrix report that is grouped off of the Column where it says Aetna, Amerihealth, Blue Cross Blue Shield etc. Then it is grouped by the row IN. However what I am finding is if a specific value for IN does not show up under a specific column it leaves a blank spot and skips down in line where it is in other rows. Basically I want each set of columns to be separate and always sort top to bottom instead of leaving blank rows. Second image shows how I want it to render.

I have however hit a dead end trying to google the correct answer to this. Any help is much appreciated!

[image: Before]

[image: After]